# Get authorization for google drive api calls in ruby with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, httparty

i want to have authorization access, for google drive api calls.

I use ruby, and HTTParty gem.

I followed this quickstart sample: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby

Then, i want to used HTTParty for use this API, and i understand that i have to get an authorization with the user's access_token obtained with the credentials above, but when i tried this code `HTTParty.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about', headers: {'Authorization' => "Bearer #{service.authorization.access_token}"})`

i've got this error status :
`...."code"=>400, "message"=>"The 'fields' parameter is required for this method."}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>,....`

My goal is to make some tests about the usage of Google Drive API.

How should i have an authorization access for this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question !

My error was not on the Authorization, but on the fields request parameter that i'd forgot!

`HTTParty.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=kind,user', headers: {'Authorization' => "Bearer #{service.authorization.access_token}"})` for example.

thank's to this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance?authuser=0#partial

see you !